# MVC Save Page Model's List of Custom Items on Submit to use in Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list of custom objects called DocumentDTO that is created and filled with values upon the page loading. When the page is submitted, I need to submit the values from the list to use in the controller post method.

Is there a way to do that for list items with custom objects? Im able to do it when its a list of strings, but its not working when its custom objects

For other fields I do this:

```
 < input asp-for="FileID" type="hidden" />
```

And for string lists I do this:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StringList.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="StringList[i]" type="text">
    }
```

But I have this Model:

```
public class FileModel
{
     public string Email { get; set; }

     public string FileNumber { get; set; }

     public List<DocumentDTO> DocumentListing { get; set; }

    public class DocumentDTO
    {
    
        public string DocName { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }

        public int docID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But both of the attempts below do not allow me to see the list items in Controller's Post method on submit (The list says it has a count of 0)

```
int DocumentsCount = Model.DocumentListing.Count();


 for (int i = 0; i < DocumentsCount; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="DocumentListing[i].DocName" type="hidden">
    <input asp-for="DocumentListing[i].docID" type="hidden">
    <input asp-for="DocumentListing[i].Comments" type="hidden">
}
```

Is this possible to do this and if possible can someone please help?

Comment: Hi @user9758771,Please be sure remove the invalid inputs in your razor view.That is to say,remove `<input asp-for"DocumentListing" type="hidden">` and `<input asp-for="DocumentListing[i]" type="hidden">`.Then you could post data successfully to backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.

In your code,you have `DocumentListing` and `DocumentListing[i]` and `DocumentListing[i].DocName` in your razor view.But `DocumentListing` and `DocumentListing[i]` is invalid that model binding could not look for the corresponding property for them.

Be sure remove invalid inputs and post valid properties to the backend:

```
@model FileModel
@{int DocumentsCount = Model.DocumentListing.Count(); }
<form asp-action="Create">
    @*<input asp-for="DocumentListing" type="hidden">*@          //remove this

    @for (int i = 0; i < DocumentsCount; i++)
    {
        Model.DocumentListing.Add(Model.DocumentListing.ElementAtOrDefault(i));

        @*<input asp-for="DocumentListing[i]" type="hidden">*@    //remove this
        <input asp-for="DocumentListing[i].DocName" type="hidden">
    }
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
```

### Update:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "DocumentListing")]List<DocumentDTO> model)
{
    //...
    return View();
}
```

Or:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(FileModel model)
{
    //...
    return View();
}
```

Check your html in frontend should be like below:

[image]

### Update2:

[image]

Comment: Alright good to know, I just pulled them out. Interestingly the model passed through with post still doesnt have any list items in it. Is it possible to pass the list items? And I noticed those hidden fields end up passed on the form itself, just not through the model. Im not sure why that is.

Comment: Hi @user9758771,could you please update your razor view?Otherwise I can't reproduce the issue.Thank you.

Comment: Sure I just updated it. Ideally Id just like to pass each entire DocumentListing object in the list to the post request. Thanks

Comment: A bit unbelievable that I used your code and still could pass the data to backend successfully.Be sure your backend action contains `[HttpPost]` also reveive model should be `FileModel`.I think you need check the input name in browser.The name of input should be like:`name="DocumentListing[0].DocName"`Just press F12 and check like following gif:https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PkkR.gif

Comment: If your backend reveived model is not `FileModel`,you also could use `[Bind(Prefix = "DocumentListing")]List<DocumentDTO> model`.

Comment: Hi @user9758771,check my updated answer,I think which is more detailed and could help you how to trouble shooting.

Comment: Thanks for updating and I'll look into it more. I did confirm that is how its showing in the browser for me. So in the post method, you had the model's DocumentListing list populated with values? Are you using .net Core?

Comment: Yes.I use .Net Core and the DocumentListing list populated with values.You could see the gif I updated in the answer.

Comment: BTW,If still does not work for you,I suggest you could create a new asp.net core mvc project and check if it could work well or not.Or if you share whole code to us will be more helpful.

Comment: Yeah its still not working.... Thats so strange that I see that its working for you and thats exactly what I have, but for me its showing that the list has 0 items in it. I think Im going to rethink the strategy for this because it is more complicated than I posted and there can be a lot of items in that list so I dont want to have like 1,000 hidden fields. I might repost later on, but thank you so much for your advice

Comment: You are welcome.Waiting for your response and may you suceed.